# Would storing large chunk of json data in Hooks Context increase server memory usage?

Tags: redux, react-hooks

I have read that it is recommended to store data in a store or a context due to the fact that data in the store can be used in any component.

For example in an e-commerce app. I have seen the cart icon which displays the number of items using the Redux Store or Hooks Context to store those numbers and also when click on the cart icon, the items display on the cart page is also using Redux Store or Hooks Context.

My question is using Amazon.com as an example, there are 12 million of products and when users logged out and log in again, they are still able to access to products in their carts. So in this case, is the Redux Store or Hooks Context relevant? And if so, which part? Of course, using Redux Store or Hooks Context to store user profile and authentication is understandable.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line essentially answers the question. In order to have persistent cart data it must be stored in a database that has to be read from each time you need it. You save the number of reads by storing it locally.

Without redux you would have to read from the database each time you wanted to know what was in the cart.

With redux you read it once and access it from any component.